# Formatting Issue in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple Point class in Python that will be able to do some simple trigonometric calculations between either another point object or simply another set of argument-passed coordinates.

The issue that I am facing is that when I pass another `Point` object as a parameter to the `distance_from_point` method, Python does not treat its attributes as integer data types when being returned from inherited functions `getx()` and `gety()`.

I tried converting the passed argument as a Point object but it doesn't seem to retain the integer value returned from either of the get methods.

Here is my class:

```
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def getx(self):
        return self._x

    def gety(self):
        return self._y

    def distance_from_xy(self, x, y):
        return math.sqrt(self.getx()*x + self.gety()*y)

    def distance_from_point(self, point):
        myPoint = Point(point)
        return math.sqrt(self.getx()* myPoint.getx() + self.gety()*myPoint.gety())


point1 = Point(0, 0)
point2 = Point(1, 1)
print(point1.distance_from_point(point2))
print(point2.distance_from_xy(2, 0))
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(point1.distance_from_point(point2))
  File "main.py", line 19, in distance_from_point
    return math.sqrt(self.getx()* myPoint.getx() + self.gety()*myPoint.gety())
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Point'
```

If myPoint inherits from the Point class, shouldn't it see the get methods, which should also return integer values from another Point object? Am I understanding this correctly/on the right track?

Comment: Thanks! I thought myPoint = Point(point) was inheritance. Title changed!

Comment: ``Point(point)`` means ``Point(x=point)`` (with ``y=0.0`` per default), not ``Point(x=point.getX(), y=point.getY())``. If you want to construct a ``Point`` from a ``Point``, you must explicitly enable this; consider to remove ``myPoint = Point(point)`` either way, it does not seem to have any benefit here.

Answer (score 0):

you pass a class instance of point to your method.

```py
print(point1.distance_from_point(point2))
```

So now in your class method

```py
    def distance_from_point(self, point):
        myPoint = Point(point)
        return math.sqrt(self.getx()* myPoint.getx() + self.gety()*myPoint.gety())
```

the local variable here is an instance of Point. you then pass that variable to create a a new Point object(there is no need for this). You are then passing to the point object a point instance. so x on the new myPoint object is now set as an instance of point not an int. just remove that line completly and refer to the local variable point which is a Point instance.

```py
    def distance_from_point(self, point):
        return math.sqrt(self.getx() * point.getx() + self.gety() * point.gety())
```

Comment: Thanks Chris! The error message went away, but I am getting 0.0 for the result when it should be 1.4142135623730951. I don't think it's doing the operations as intended for that second method.

Comment: @arsenA, have you investigated the values of the x and y from self and point - for example - add this line before the return in `distance_from_poin()` :
`print(f'{self.getx()},{self.gety()} -> {point.getx()},{point.gety()}')`

Comment: when i run this code I get two things printed, the first is 0 and it shold be. `0*1 + 0*1 = 0` so the srqt of that will be 0. For the second print i get exactly what you listed